# Spectrum of an element

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, spectral-theory

I'm having a little trouble calculating the spectrum of an element: specifically, the element $f(x) = \frac{1}{x}$, as an element of the **bounded** continuous functions from $[1, \infty)$ with pointwise multiplication and the sup norm.

I'm aware the spectrum of an element is $\sigma(x) = \{ \lambda \in \mathbb{C} : x - \lambda \mathbb{1} $ is not invertible $\}$, (an element is invertible if $\exists\ y\ s.t.\ xy = yx = 1$) and I'm guessing my tired brain is doing something stupid, but by my reckoning is that $\frac{1}{x} - \lambda$ is non-invertible if $\lambda \in (0, 1)$

However, to get that answer, I seem to be doing nothing more than making a wild guess / can't at all prove that this must be the case. Can anyone help me with either the construction of a proof, or give me a reason that this answer is way off and tell me where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's clear that if $\lambda \in (0,1)$, $1/x - \lambda$ is not invertible because its value at $x=1/\lambda$ is $0$.  Next: what about $\lambda = 0$ and $\lambda = 1$.  What could $y$ be in those cases?  Next: what about all other $\lambda$ in the complex  plane?

By the way, since you mention sup norm: I think you must be talking about **bounded** continuous functions.

Comment: Hmm, I guess the case $\lambda = 1$ should definitely be in there; given x = 1 is allowed $1 - 1$ won't be invertible if this is the case. I wasn't too sure about the 0 case; though I guess there's probably a claim about the closure of the set (otherwise I mightn't be able to invert it?). As for all other $\lambda$, they should be fair game, since there won't be any zeros in $1/x - \lambda$.
Is this argument valid?

Comment: Ah, yes, thanks for picking up on bounded. Will make this edit.

Comment: Explicitly, what is the inverse element $y$ in these cases?  Is it a bounded continuous function on $[1,\infty)$?

Comment: The inverse is $1/(y + \lambda)$, and this is both bounded and continuous since $\lambda$ and $y$ will be non-zero (bounded inverse theorem here probably now suffices since it's invertible and one-to-one?)

Comment: For $\lambda = 0$, $1/(y + 0) = x$ is not bounded.

Comment: Yeah, I realised this in the morning after I woke up; I figured I needed the closure when working on this, but at the time couldn't properly work out why. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

A few things, first when you are considering $f(x)$ as an operator in must be inside a $C^*$-algebra. You say you are considering it as an elements of continuous functions on $[1, \infty)$ with pointwise multiplication and sup norm, but this isn't such an algebra. There are generally two $C^*$-algebras that one would consider in this case.

i.) $C_0([1, \infty))$ the algebra of continuous function vanishing at $\infty$

ii.) $C_b([1, \infty))$ the algebra of bounded continuous functions.

Note that in order to talk about invertible you need the algebra to be unital so the first one is out. So now I will assume you mean the second.

Recall that the spectrum is a compact subset of $\mathbb{C}$. Now $\lambda\in\sigma(f)\Leftrightarrow f(x)-\lambda$ is not invertible $\Leftrightarrow \frac{1}{f(x)-\lambda}$ is not in $C_b([1, \infty))\Leftrightarrow\frac{1}{\frac{1}{x}-\lambda}\not\in C_b([1, \infty))\Leftrightarrow 0\in \overline{\{\frac{1}{x}-\lambda: x\in[1, \infty)\}}\Leftrightarrow \lambda\in[0, 1]$

Comment: Yeah, I guess the edit must have been slow to load, but Robert pointed out I missed the word 'bounded' in my original post -- apologies. I guess the issue I was having was that I couldn't reconcile the $\lambda = 0$ case easily, but I think it's perhaps far beyond my bedtime because I realise now that the 0 is needed for compactness, since $\sigma(x)$ is compact for a unital Banach algebra. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Also you need the zero because you need the inverse to be bounded. The inverse of $\frac{1}{x}$ is $x$ which is not bounded so $\frac{1}{x}=\frac{1}{x}-0$ is not invertible.